# Package tymondesigns/jwt-auth installation problem in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-6

I've installed a fresh Laravel 6 project. However, when I attempt to install the `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` package via...

`composer require tymon/jwt-auth`

or

`composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop`

It displays the following error.

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for tymon/jwt-auth dev-develop -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[dev-develop].
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - tymon/jwt-auth dev-develop requires illuminate/http ^5.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev,
>   5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18,5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0,
>   v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28,
>   v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0,
>   v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27,
>   v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33,
>   v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41,
>   v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11,v5.6.12, v5.6.13,
>   v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21,
>   v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28,
>   v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35,
>   v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7,
>   v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15,
>   v5.7.2,v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28,
>   v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0,
>   v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2,
>   v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30,
>   v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
>       - don't install illuminate/http 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/http 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/http 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/http 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/http 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/http 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
>       ........................

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new version JWT package was tagged for laravel 6!

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0-rc.5
```

Answer (score 1):

**`tymondesigns/jwt-auth`** package doesn't support Laravel 6 yet

There is PR on GitHub https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/pull/1861 just wait it closed

Answer (score 1):

**laravel8:**

```
composer require -w tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs
```

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4.1",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
    "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5|dev-develop",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am installing the following:

composer require tymon/jwt-auth "dev-develop"

Laravel 6.* updated on branch develop - tymon/jwt-auth

Comment: `composer require tymon/jwt-auth "dev-develop"`